# Microstation Elements created in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dxf, microstation, terrascan

In my workflow I typically, in Microstation V8 2004 Edition, manually place a shape element around a series of imported coordinates to use as a fence for loading point cloud data in TerraScan.  I am trying to incorporate QGIS into my workflow doing the following:

1. Importing and buffering my coordinate file in QGIS
2. Editing the file until my buffer is one continuous polygon
3. Simplifying the geometries so I am under approx. 100 nodes
4. Converting the polygon to a line shapefile
5. Exporting this shapefile to .dxf format for use in Microstation

My issue is that when I attach the .dxf file to my working DGN, and merge it into the master (effectively making it an element), Microstation is not recognizing it as a valid fence and won't constrain the point import to with my desired area.

I am wondering if there is an issue with the geometry, from the way I created the line file in QGIS?

DXF files containing line polygons converted in Global Mapper (from different source data) work as expected - that is, they constrain the data in the same way an that an element does when I create it manually within Microstation. So I have also tried importing my QGIS line shapefile into Global Mapper and exporting it as a .dxf, but this file does not work either - leading me back to it being a QGIS issue.

Anyone have any thoughts or tried to do this before?

I am a relatively new QGIS user, with Version 2.4.0-Chugiak

Comment: I'm also working on better interface between QGIS and Microstation. And the main issue is the DGN format... Are you still trying ?